# create a query in visual studio to connect 2 or 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I have the following 3 tables:

```
customer   (cid,cname,bid)
booking    (bid,bdate,btime,billamt)
bill       (billdate,billamt,billid,cid,bid)
```

I want to view `cname,bdate,btime,billdate and billamt` in visual basic form's respective textboxes. 
Please help me with creating Query. And how to use the query to copy values to the respective textboxes in the form.

Comment: Hi @Kiaara, welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you taken a couple of minutes to read the FAQ's? Do it now, you will get a badge for that too. Then come back and be sure that you are asking correctly. Check  this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write and ask a good question.

Comment: Please also know that VBA is different from VB.NET... Please read about each tag or language to understand in which language you need the programming help.. it's important to tag your question correctly to get the attention from who can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start for SQL Query using `JOINs` to connect your tables. You must try out **populating** Form controls via SQL to get a better understanding of what you are doing. IF you are stuck again, you can post a question here.

```
SELECT C.cname,BO.bdate,BO.btime, BL.billdate, BL.billamt
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Bill
ON C.cid = BL.cid
INNER JOIN Booking
BL.bid = BO.bid
WHERE = ? -- specify proper conditions as you desire
```

So if you use databinding, you can use `DataTable`, `DataGridView` where `TextBox` be bound as well.
Here is a sample snippet.

```
`DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable1
`TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", DataTable1, "Column2")
```

If you use `BindingSource`, here is how you can filter out. I prefer to do a fullfetch of customers from SQL Table into `DataTable` and then query within (filter) using paramter (e.g. in your case `cid`)

```
//assuming TextBox1 has cid (customer ID)
customersBindingSource.Filter = "cid ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
```

References:

- How to populate Form controls: TextBox, ListBox etc using VB.NET SQL
- Please read about **DATA BINDING**
- As well as `BindingSource`

Comment: i learned about datagridview but there all the details of ALL the customers will be shown. Whereas i want to view is the joined details of ONLY 1 CUSTOMER based on customer id

Comment: Sending a `cid` as a parameter to `WHERE` clause or filtering `datagridview` by `cid`